# system for bidirectional realtime communication between tablets and server

Tags: android, sockets, cordova, real-time, tablet

We are going to build a multiplayer game. 
The idea is that every player has a tablet and is connected to a server. 
The server should control the game logic, while the clients (the tablets) will only serve as a frontend to the game.
We need to make a decision about the frameworks/programming language we are going to use.
A crossplatform frontend would be cool, but is not mandatory. It has to run on Android devices at least.
The communication between the server and the client must be bidirectional and realtime.
We don't care about a small amount of delay.

Currently we consider an HTML5 client in combination with a javascript server (running upon nodejs) to be the best option.
The communication would be managed by the javascript library socket.io.
The HTML5 frontend can be run either in-browser or as an app (built with PhoneGap).

However we did not decide yet since we want to be sure to make the right choice.
There might be frameworks that can do a better job.
Does anyone know a better solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Play 2 is great for this well, but node/socket are great choices too.  I would use backbone.js for the front end as it gives you a lot of flexibility and it's easy to keep the views in sync.  (there is an example of such an app on my github if you're interested)

Comment: where is your github link?